# Iphone Apps using C#/Mono

Tags: c#, iphone, ios4, mono

There are various questions (mainly around 2009 to early 2010) discussing use of the Mono framework to write apps in C# and deploy them to iPhone.  Also there is some discussion of the Unity Framework, but I'm more interested in a fairly standard UI app.

Has anyone successfully developed and released a commercial quality app using C#/Mono?  If so, what were the lessons learnt?  Pain points?  If you know of other people who have done so, how have they fared?

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic answer is yes, there are a lot of applications out there that have been developed using MonoTouch.  You can find some nice numbers on Novell's site but there are a ton of games and other application is the AppStore that were developed using MonoTouch.

I would start your investigation by going to review articles that walk through the good and bad of MonoTouch.  For example, here is a good starting place:

http://www.bryanthankins.com/techblog/2010/01/17/monotouch-review-porting-an-obj-c-app/

http://www.devproconnections.com/article/mobile-development/review-monotouch-enterprise

Then I would look through some tutorials to see how exactly this is done so you can see if it will fit in your environment.  There are a lot out there that show off how to use MonoTouch, including these:

http://vimeo.com/6689472

http://blog.keen-edge.com/category/monotouch/

Finally, I would look at what is happening currently with Attachmate and the takeover of Novell.  There are some real issues there that may cause you to reconsider going with MonoTouch.  For example, while Mono's future may be unclear at Attachmate, it seems that it might be continued through another company:

http://ostatic.com/blog/mono-continues-without-novell-attachmate

This uncertainty might not be what you want in a project you are counting on so you need to work through that before committing.

Comment: http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2011/05/monotouchmonodroid-and-xamarin-what-now.html

Comment: Thanks guys for the links.  I had only just started looking into it and hadn't realised the takeover had occurred.  Sounds like a holding pattern should be taken until Xamarin appears!  Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Glinkot - I would agree with your assessment.  It is very unfortunate that this happened, but since the market seems to be there I would imagine Xamarin will be a success eventually.

Comment: Can I develop apps with MonoTouch using MonoDevelop?